# Every ideal is generated by two elements in $k[x^2, x^3]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Let $k$ be a field, and consider the subring $k[x^2,x^3]$ of $k[x]$. Prove that every ideal in $k[x^2,x^3]$ can be generated by two elements.

What I have tried is: suppose $I$ is a nonzero ideal in $k[x^2,x^3]$; we may choose a polynomial with least degree to be one of the generators. But I have no idea about the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f$ to be a polynomial of minimal degree $d$. If $g\in I$ has degree
$d'\ge d+2$ then $g-x^{d'-d}f$ is also in $I$ and has degree $<d'$.
Keep going: there is $q\in k[x^2,x^3]$ such that $h=g-qf$ has degree $\le d+1$. If $h$ has degree $d+1$ you can then show that $I=(f,h)$: indeed
$I=k[x^2,x^3]f+kh$. If this never happens for any $g\in I$ then $I=(f)$
already.

ADDED IN EDIT

Actually in the 2-generator case I think one can take $h=xf$.

Comment: $xf$ could be a polynomial which doesn't belong to $k[x^2,x^3]$ as in the case $I=(x^2-1,x^3-1)$.